# Built-in dataset in Python package

Tags: python, csv, package, dataset, built-in

I made a Python package that I want to upload to PyPI. I want the package to have built-in dataset based on the csv file. Package has the folder 'load' that contains csv files necessary for built-in datasets.

Could you help please?

I made this code but it does not work

```
def load_data():

    file_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('package', 'load/data.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    return df
```

I expect to call function `load_data()` that will show my dataset.

Comment: "Can you help?" is not a valid question on SO. What is your exact issue? [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If you use a setup.py you can add a package_data tgat refers to the file locations in you package ike so:

```
package_data = {
    '': [
        'src/myfolder/thing1.csv',
        'src/myfolder/thing2.csv',
    ],
}
```

more information [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) and [here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/create-and-publish-your-own-python-package-ea45bee41cdc)